# How to efficiently iterate variable number in Selenium Webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I am using selenium webdriver with Python on IE and the code mentioned below is working fine but I need to make this in a loop.
Please suggest.
termsName0 may be 2 ,3 4 or N numbers

Code:

```
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName0")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName1")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName3")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use try except contract if you do not know the "N".

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException

try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        name = "termsName" + str(i)
        Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name(name).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
        i +=1
 except (ElementNotVisibleException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. N specifies how many times you want to loop

```
N = 4

for i in range(N):
    name = "termsName" + str(i)
    Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name(name).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
```

Basically it takes the number of the current iteration and appends that to `"termsName"`.

Above code is equivalent to

```
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName0")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName1")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName2")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("termsName3")).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but I dont know the N = 4 , this may change on UI , some times 1 some times 6 . In that case If I defined N =4 then above code will fail.

Comment: @user3702349 how is N acquired? You can change N. You just need to set N equal to the number that you get from the UI

Comment: Actually on my page value for N will vary.

Comment: @user3702349 I know. You have a piece of code that gets the value for N from the ui? You need to assign N to that value

Comment: Last query:Actually on my page value for N will vary. Would it be possible to first check termsname and then take out the value of N and then use Loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. Could you include the code that gets  the value for N from the ui pleasE?

Answer (score 0):

For iterating variable number of items you could try something like this

```
#To fetch all elements start with termsName 
element_list = firefox_driver.find_elements_by_id("termsName[0-9]*")

# below code will iterate over the all links
for i in range(len(element_list)):
        name = "termsName" + str(i)
        Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name(name).select_by_visible_text("Blank No Text")
```

Hope it helps.